# Could not Remote Login or Ping server

Tags: remote-desktop, ping

This morning I applied the Windows updates on a Windows Server 2008 SP2.

On system restart, I was no longer able to ping the system or log in remotely.

This server is managed remotely, so I was not able to view the reboot process.

When chatting to the guy at the data centre where it is housed, he relayed that it was at the logon screen and would be able to login had he access.

He hard rebooted the system and I was able to reach the server once more.

There is a time gap in the system event logs, so I don't know where else to look in order to find out what happened.

If any more information is needed please let me know.

I really need to find the solution to this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Microsoft Update KB2667402 (critical update, patches a vulnerability in terminal services) has been known to cause this.  For me, installing the "next" group of patches always seemed to restore terminal services, but others have had success with uninstalling the patch and reinstalling it manually, on its own.  The lack of detail in your post makes it hard to say if this is the case for you or not, but it's worth a look - see if KB2667402 was one of the updates installed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did ask if I needed to add more info in my initial post ;)
I'll have a look for that KB in the installed updates

Comment: Nothing found in regards to that KB. As far as I can see that KB is for Windows 7 and server I am working with is Server 2008